# Put several intengers into a list to get the maximum number

Tags: python, list, max

I'm really new to Python but I have a question, that I can't answer with google oder stackoverlow. Mainly because I don't know what to type into the search field as "integers into list" does not get me the result I want...

My problem is the following. I have a number of input files and I open one after the other to get the information stored in these files. In the first line of each file is a number (the number of atoms - it's a program for chemistry) from 2 up to X. X is so the maximum number of atoms.
What I need now is to find out the maximum number of atoms.

What I tried: I read the first line of every file and I also get the NA (number of atoms), but I get them separately as an integer. What I now want is to store all these numbers into ONE list, so I can make max(List) and I get the ???
I hope you understand what I mean... :)

Here is the part of my Code:

```
def openfiles(dateiname):
    """opens an input file"""
    f = open('./files/dsgdb9nsd.xyz/' + dateiname,'r')

    lineList = f.readlines()
    NA = int(lineList[0])
```

then follows something else and then:

```
for d in range(0,2):
        datei = filenames[d]
        aMolecule = openfiles(datei)
        myNA = aMolecule[3]
        print myNA
```

Solution: I can now make a list with all myNA by making

```
myListofNA=[]
for d in range(0,2):
        datei = filenames[d]
        aMolecule = openfiles(datei)
        myNA = aMolecule[3]
        myListofNA.append(myNA)
print max(myListofNA)
```

Thanks, that solved my problem! I didn't thought of making the max(myListofNA) outside the loop.

Best wishes,
straumle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like

```
# create an empty list object
myListofNA = []
for d in range(0,2):
    datei = filenames[d]
    aMolecule = openfiles(datei)
    myNA = aMolecule[3]
    print myNA
    # each time append a new entry to the list
    myListofNA.append(myNa)

# search the maximum element of the list
print max(myListofNA)
```

I'm missing a `return` statement at the end of `openfiles`. May look into that to. Try to give each function one concern.

Comment: I have a return statement, I just didn't include it as this is not the whole code and not the whole function. But thank you anyway for noticing :D

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `for` loop with the following list comprehension

```
myListofNA = [openfiles(filenames[i])[3] for i in range(2)]
```

Or to keep the for loop, you could create a `list` before the loop, and `append` a value each iteration.

```
myListofNA = []
for d in range(0,2):
    datei = filenames[d]
    aMolecule = openfiles(datei)
    myNA = aMolecule[3]
    print myNA
    myListofNA.append(myNA)
```